# PowerShell Positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Get-WindowsFeature'

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2

### Calling out for some PowerShell help again !!

I have the below which is trying to connect to a remote machine and return all the installed WindowsFeatures.. then I will try to export the list (but I have not been able to that far yet).

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName VM01 -ScriptBlock { Get-Module ServerManager Get-WindowsFeature | Where-Object{$_.Installed -match "True" } | Select-Object -Property Name } -credential TestUser01
```

After running the above I am correctly presented with a login screen to allow me to enter a password then the following error appears, I don't believe I know enough about PowerShell and the use of Positional parameters;

```
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Get-WindowsFeature'.
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Module], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetModuleCommand
```

Any pointing in the right direction will be a great help !! thanks guys and girls.

Comment: Agh @jisaak thank you very much !!

Comment: Your welcome. I just added it as an answer since it probably was the solution for your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You miss a `;` after `ServerManager`also, you probably mean `Import-Module`instead of `Get-Module`:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName VM01 -ScriptBlock { Import-Module ServerManager; Get-WindowsFeature | Where-Object{$_.Installed -match "True" } | Select-Object -Property Name } -credential TestUser01
```